# El formulario llega vacío al servidor

Tags: php, html, formularios

Al enviar el formulario desde la página me llega pero vacío. Les comparto el código:

Éste es el HTML:

```
<form action="enviar.php">
  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="fname">Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="lname2">Apellido</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="subject2">Asunto</label>
      <input type="text" id="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un asunto">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <label for="message2">Mensaje</label>
      <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Indique si asistirá acompañado y de tener alguna restricción alimenticia no olvides avisarnos."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary">
  </div>
</form>
```

Les comparto el php:

```
<?php
  $destino="oliverdto@gmail.com";
  $nombre=$_POST["fname"];
  $correo=$_POST["email"];;
  $mensaje=$_POST["subject"];
  $contenido="Nombre: ".$nombre."\nCorreo: ".$correo."\nMensaje: ".$mensaje;
  mail($destino,"Contacto", $contenido);
  header("Location: index.html");
?>
```

Comment: Debes agregar el atributo `name="valor"` a todos los campos que deseas enviar por el formulario. Lo que estas haciendo es obtener los datos por el id, en vez de usar name

Comment: @Hexyz si alguna de las respuestas te sirvió de ayuda o resolvió el problema, deberías votarla positivo y/o marcarla como aceptada. De ese modo otros usuarios que tengan un problema similar, podrán identificar la respuesta que te sirvió. Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) para más información.

Comment: Ya lo hice :) muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada al a la etiqueta "form" le debes agregar el atributo method="POST" quedando:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST">
```

Además también a la etiqueta input les debes agregar el atributo "name". Ej:

```
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre">
```

y así a todas las etiquetas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, no sabes cuanto me ayudo y usando eso que compartiste pude aplicarlo en otros modelos de formularios :D a donde vamos por las cervezas?

Answer (score 2):

En html existen 2 métodos de envío de formularios, que son son **GET** y **POST**, después de enviar los datos son almacenados en sus respectivas variables superglobales de PHP `$_GET` y `$_POST`, así  como en `$_REQUEST`.

Por defecto los formularios html envían los datos por GET, es decir si a la hora de definir el formulario no establecemos el atributo `method` el formularios se enviará por GET. Si queremos enviarlo mediante POST debemos indicarlo expresamente.

Por lo tanto los siguientes formularios serán enviados por GET

```
<form action="enviar.php">
   <input type="text" name="nombre">
</form>
```

Y

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="nombre">
</form>
```

En cambio para enviarlo mediante POST

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="nombre">
</form>
```

Los datos de los formularios más allá del método que se utilice para el envíos son enviados en pares de **`clave=valor`**, la clave es definida por el atributo `name` del input, por lo que es algo importante a la hora de definir un formulario, cuando queramos recuperar el valor de un campo desde PHP debemos utilizar el nombre del campo, es decir su `name`.

Ejemplo:

Con GET

```
<form action="enviar.php">
   <input type="text" name="nombre">
</form>
```

En **enviar.php**

```
echo $_GET['nombre'];
```

Con POST

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="nombre">
</form>
```

En **enviar.php**

```
echo $_POST['nombre'];
```

---

En el manual de php puedes encontrar varias referencias que ayudan a entender como funcionan los formularios y como son tratados en PHP:

- Tratar con formularios http://php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php
- Variables desde fuentes externas http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.external.php
- $_REQUEST http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.request.php
- $_GET http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php
- $_POST http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1):

Para que un elemento  `<input>` sea enviado con el `<form>` tiene que tener un atributo `name` que es como sera identificado en el POST, asi que intenta esto compañero:

```
  <form action="enviar.php">
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="fname">Nombre</label>
                          <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="form-control" 
                           placeholder="Nombre">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <label for="lname2">Apellido</label>
                          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellido">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <label for="subject2">Asunto</label>
                          <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese un asunto">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <label for="message2">Mensaje</label>
                          <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Indique si asistirá acompañado y de tener alguna restricción alimenticia no olvides avisarnos."></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: Hola Álvaro, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema de la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Deberías  editar la respuesta para añadir una pequeña descripción de los cambios que hiciste y por qué o cómo resuelven el problema. Lee [answer] para más información. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo en comentar Alvaro :D te confirmo que la respuesta Tonatihu me sirvió demasiado como también la tuya :)

Comment: Editada para explicar en que consiste la corrección que se hizo en el código